# Что такое console.log в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Что такое console.log в JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод console.log() выводит отладочную информацию в консоль, т.е. скрывая ее от пользователей.

Есть еще ряд похожих функций:
console.info(), console.warn() и console.error().

Все они отличаются только визуально в консоли.

Прочитайте про все плюсы http://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/

Answer (score 3):

Логирование (вывод отладочных данных, например) в консоль разработчикa.

```
console.log('Var = ' + Var);
```